# Is it possible to make custom bullets like this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

It would be better if you can do this using CSS only.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If they increase for each list item, you don't want custom bullets, you want custom numbers. Increasing per item means it is an "ordered list" ``ol` not an "unordered list" `ul`. So try googling for custom numbers instead of custom bullets.

Comment: At the time of creating `ul li` add a loop to create `*` based on the increaminting number of `li's`

Comment: sorry but didn't get any solution ...

Comment: look for 'counters'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this via pure `css` you should set it manually *(like prev answer)* but if you want to add stars dynamically, you should use something like this, there is no way to do this via pure `css` dynamically I think.

```js
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var index = $(this).index() + 1;
  var star = $('<span/>')
  for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    star.append('*');
  }
  $(this).prepend(star);
});

var l = $('ul li:last-child span').width();
$('ul li span').css('width', l);
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  display: inline;
}

ul li span {
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
  <li><a>Some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the only CSS solution available for the result you want:

You can achieve the result using [**`list-style:@counter-style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) and customize it using its option as per your need.

> **But this `@counter-style` currently works only on Firefox 33+**

```css
@counter-style cs-symbolic {
  system: symbolic;
  symbols: '*';
  range: ;
  suffix: " ";
}

ul {
  list-style: cs-symbolic;
  padding-left: 30%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="demo-list" class="demo-numeric">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

*Hope this was helpful for you. If you can use script it would be best, in following years the support will come but for now, it's not a perfect way to go with.*

Answer (score 1):

There is one way to do it but you have to do manually line by line given that you are using only CSS.

```css
ul, li {
   list-style:none      
}

li:nth-child(1):before {
   content: "*" 
}

li:nth-child(2):before {
   content: "**" 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> foo</li>
  <li> bar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i think it limited to fixed item numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the https://codepen.io/mgkrish/pen/EEVpON for dynamic li styles

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
    <ol style="text-align: left;">
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
    </ol>

    ol.HideStyle{
       list-style : none;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ol").addClass("HideStyle");

    var listLength= $( "li" ).length;
        for(i=0;i<=listLength;i++){
         var str= "*";
         var x=  str.repeat(i)
          $("ol li:nth-child(" + i + ")").prepend(x);
          console.log("X",x)

        }

      });
```